# How to use <c-i><c-o> in terminal mode to jump to/from next/previous cursor position?

Tags: key-bindings, terminal, jumplist, jump

When in terminal mode, I would like that `<c-i>` and `<c-o>` work like in insert mode, i.e. the cursor jumps to its next/previous position in accordance with the `jumplist`.

How to make this to happen?

EDIT: this becomes very annoying when you jump into a terminal window with `<c-o>` (or with `<c-i>`) and then can't get out it not with another `<c-o>` or with a `<c-i>`.

Comment: I believe in terminal mode you are limited to the possibility of the terminal and it is very likely that it is not possible.

Comment: Hum, I see. Any workaround to avoid adding entries in the `jumplist` when jumping into a terminal buffer? A common scenario is when you have a sequence of e.g. `<c-o>` and you end up in a terminal window and you won't get out from there with another `<c-o>`. Very annoying.

Comment: Vim. But actually it jumps into terminals… :/

Comment: Thank you! Very appreciated!

Comment: Is the thing where you jump into a terminal window with `<c-o>` and then can't get out the actual problem you are trying to solve? If so, could you please edit that information into the question?

Comment: @Rich Edited, thanks.

Comment: @Barzi2001 about your latest edit, I can't reproduce it. After switching to term buffer with <c-o>, I _can_ switch back with <c-i>. (Note that you have to perform <C-o> from normal mode, which you can switch to from terminal mode by <C-\><c-n>, I think.)

Comment: @kadekai Ok, so you go first from `Terminal mode` to `Normal mode` and then you make the jump? Then I could `tnoremap <c-o> <c-\><c-n><c-o>` but then the terminal would  remain in `Normal` mode. When you use some function based on `term_sendkeys()` one shall remember it. I could try and see if it resonate...

Comment: @kadekai No. It won't work. When I am on the terminal and I hit `TAB` the terminal goes in `Normal` mode.

Comment: @Barzi2001 That's because [`<C-I>` *is* `TAB`.](https://catern.com/posts/terminal_quirks.html) you can't have `<C-I>` both navigate through the jumplist and enter `TAB` characters. It has to do one or the other!

Comment: Or are you saying you *want* `TAB` to navigate the jumplist but your mapping isn't working?

Comment: I don't want `TAB` for navigating the `jumplist`, but I do want `TAB` to auto-complete words in the terminal buffer when I am running an e.g. `IPython` session. I was not aware that `<c-i>` was the same as `TAB` but that certainly make things even more messy! :D Before I key-bind `tnoremap <c-i> <c-\><c-n><c-i>` but then the auto-complete with `TAB` was gone (without such a key-binding the auto-complete based on `TAB` was working  perfectly, in-fact I removed such a key-binding).

Comment: Have you tried using `CTRL-W N CTRL-O` ? The issue seems to be, that you need to go to Terminal-Normal Mode before you can use the Vim normal mode commands

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Yes. That works but it is not the wanted behavior. :) Though I may think to `tnomap`  it,  e.g. `tnoremap <c-o> <c-w>N<c-o>` but then there is the problem for `<c-i>` since I would lose the auto-completion feature in terminal buffers if I remap `<c-i>`. I still believe that the best would be to completely prevent terminal buffers to end up in the jumplist.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/56564964e6d0/src/mark.c#L143-L144), it looks like there is no way other than `:h keepjump` to avoid adding to jumplist (which you *can* do: most of the movements can be done through `:h :norm`, and when in terminal buffer, prepending those commands with `:keepjump` *will* avoid adding the terminal buffer to the jumplist, but I suspect most people will find that workaround not a solution at all, so back to the source code):

```
    // for :global the mark is set only once
    if (global_busy || listcmd_busy || (cmdmod.cmod_flags & CMOD_KEEPJUMPS))
        return;
```

The easiest way to achieve what OP wants is adding one more condition to the above if block: a condition to check if current buffer is a terminal buffer. Below is the patch.

```
diff --git a/src/mark.c b/src/mark.c
index 584db033d3ca..b5752653ea0d 100644
--- a/src/mark.c
+++ b/src/mark.c
@@ -143,6 +143,9 @@ setpcmark(void)
     if (global_busy || listcmd_busy || (cmdmod.cmod_flags & CMOD_KEEPJUMPS))
    return;
 
+    if (curbuf->b_term != NULL)
+      return;
+
     curwin->w_prev_pcmark = curwin->w_pcmark;
     curwin->w_pcmark = curwin->w_cursor;
```

You can apply it by copying it to your clipboard and using `${PASTECMD} | patch -p1`, where `$PASTECMD` is the command associated with your clipboard for pasting.

For `xclip`:

```
xclip -selection clipboard -o | patch -p1
```

NOTE that the last empty line in the patch is expected (although not required) by `patch`.

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/11345

Answer (score 0):

As it's likely not possible to do what you want, if it's a *nix terminal you could use `tmux` to jump back through terminal history in `copy-mode`.There are various plugins which can make this faster, like:

- [tmux-jump](https://github.com/schasse/tmux-jump)
- [tmux-fuzzback](https://github.com/roosta/tmux-fuzzback)
- [tmux-thumbs](https://github.com/fcsonline/tmux-thumbs)

You could disable the `tmux` statusline when running in vim terminal to reduce visual clutter.

Comment: Good to know! But unfortunately I use Win 10.